# How I can delete lines which have less than 11 numbers but more than 8 numbers in one line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, notepad

How I can delete lines which have less than 11 numbers but more than 8 numbers in one line in notepad++. The numbers are separeted from each other with letters or spaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement says to remove lines having 9 or 10 digits, but not more or less than this.  You may try using lookaheads to handle this.  In regex mode, try finding the following pattern:

```
^(?!.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d)(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d).*
```

Then just replace that with empty string (nothing).  Follow the demo below to see that the pattern correctly flags the appropriate lines.

### Demo

**Edit:**

Here is another pattern you may use, without lookaheads, which is a bit easier on the eyes:

```
^\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d?\D*$
```

This again says to match any line which contains either 9 or 10 digits, but not more or less than this.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:\D*\d){8}(?:\D*\d){0,3}(?:\R|$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  (?:\D*\d){8}      # non capture group, 0 or more NON digit and 1 digit, may appear 8 times
  (?:\D*\d){0,3}    # non capture group, 0 or more NON digit and 1 digit, may appear 0 upto 3 times
(?:\R|$)            # non capture group, linebreak or end of file
```

**Given:**

```
1234567
12345678
123456789
1234567890
12345678901
123456789012
a1b2c3d4e5f6g7
a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8
a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9
a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2
```

**Result for given example:**

```
1234567
123456789012
a1b2c3d4e5f6g7
a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2
```

**Screen capture:**
[image]